# Is it possible to use third party UI widgets with MeteorJS?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have just discovered MeteorJS framework and its innovative concepts are very appealing to me. Having real-time seamless updates is very valuable. Their new Blaze layout engine also seems very compelling. Above all, the main appeal to me is that Meteor is a full stack solution, which implies, that there is no need to ply in anything else, in order to achieve a modern Web app. That being said, I was unable to find a complete Meteor app example, featuring top-shelf polished UI.
My question is: is it possible/supportable/recommended to use a third party Web UI widgets, like KendoUI, within Meteor ecosystem? Granted, I have only been looking at Meteor for 1.5 days, but I wonder - how would any third party Web UI widgets fit into the concept/implementation of reactive templates - i.e. two-way bindings-wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the easy answer is that yes Meteor is perfectly suitable for complex UI, and Blaze has been optimized for jQuery at this point, so if the framework is based on that (And most are these days) then everything will work.

In a nutshell, mapping a framework really just means making the UI javascript available, instantiating it either in the HTML template with a div tag etc, or instantiating it with a template helper function, which you can make "reactive" - In other words that code changes whenever the underlying data source changes.

By reacting to event handlers and setting reactive variables, you essentially get a model->view->controller style application that updates automatically.

You can look at a full example app here:
https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope

and of course you should get a copy of their eBook: https://www.discovermeteor.com/ since it walks you through the making of Microscope.